# How can I change the type of cell in uitableview with a button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have two `UIButtons` that act like a `segmented control`. I also have two custom `UITableView cells`, and I the user to be able to toggle between the two types of cells with the buttons. Does anyone know how I can do this? Here is some code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *videoCellID = @"videoCellID";
    static NSString *commentCellID = @"commentCellID";
    static NSString *relatedCellID = @"relatedCellID";

    VideoDetailCell *videoCell;

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        videoCell = (VideoDetailCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:videoCellID];
        if (!videoCell)
        {
            videoCell = [VideoDetailCell generateCellWithInfo:nil];
            videoCell.navigation = self.navigationController;
        }
        return videoCell;
    }
    else
    {
        if (videoCell.buttonSelected == 0)
        {
            self.cellType = 0;
            CommentCell *commentCell = (CommentCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:commentCellID];
            if (!commentCell)
            {
                commentCell = [CommentCell generateCellWithInfo:nil];
            }
            return commentCell;
        }
        else
        {
            self.cellType = 1;
            RelatedCell *related = (RelatedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:relatedCellID];
            if (!related)
            {
                related = [RelatedCell generateCellWithInfo:nil];
            }
            return related;
        }
    }
}
```

The `videoCell` is another custom `UITableViewCell`, but that will always be the first cell in the UITableView. There is a UIButton to show the `commentCell`, and one to show the `relatedCell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have set `videoCell.buttonSelected` according to your button action call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.